# $state.go and nav direction

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I have a ui-sref link.

```
<a ui-sref="tab.search-results(backTo)" nav-direction="back" class="button no-margin-top bold button-full button-stable">
  <span class="assertive">BACK</span>
</a>
```

I'm using `nav-direction` to have the transition go back. How do I do this with `$state.go()`?

```
<a ng-click="parts.goBack()" class="button no-margin-top bold button-full button-stable">
  <span class="assertive">BACK</span>
</a>
```

I don't see this option anywhere.

```
function goBack( ) {
  // How do I go back via nav direction?
  $state.go('tab.search-results');
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [$ionicHistory](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/). It has a `goBack([backCount])` function which looks like exactly what you need.